# Starting libGdx from android code

Tags: android, android-intent, libgdx

I am making android- specific game, and would like to use android API's. But I'm wondering, is it possible to have like an android menu, and from there call libGdx? I've tried adapting the manifest in the android part, so android activity (menu) is the LAUNCHER activity and gets called first. Then I thought I could start the ApplicationListener with an intent, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple:

```
// my call of the loading screen from inside a fragment
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoadingScreenActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and the LoadingScreenActivity is, guess what, an Activity.

```
// the onCreate method
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useGL20 = true;
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    initialize(new LoadingScreen(), cfg);
}
```

and LoadingScreen is the the ApplicationListener you already mentioned

```
public class LoadingScreen implements ApplicationListener {
    // create(), resize() and more
}
```

So basically you need embed libgdx inside an Activity...

**Edit:**

Here is my complete loading screen activity which uses libgdx. It should work (just remove the CustomApplication stuff that you don't have).

```
public class LoadingScreenActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = LoadingScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;
        cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
        cfg.useCompass = false;

        initialize(new LoadingScreen(), cfg);
    }

    private class LoadingScreen implements ApplicationListener {
        private OrthographicCamera mCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        private SpriteBatch mBatch;
        private Stage mStage;
        private ShapeRenderer mProgressLine;

        @Override
        public void create() {
            AssetManager manager = CustomApplication.getAssetManager();
            manager.load("ic_launcher.png", Texture.class);

            mStage = new Stage();
            mProgressLine = new ShapeRenderer();

            mBatch = new SpriteBatch();

            mCamera.setToOrtho(false, DesignUtil.getScreenWidth(), DesignUtil.getScreenHeight());
            mStage.setCamera(mCamera);
        }

        @Override
        public void resize(int width, int height) {
            mStage.setViewport(width, height, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void render() {
            if (CustomApplication.getAssetManager().update()) {
                IntentUtil.startActivity(LoadingScreenActivity.this, GameActivity.class);
                finish();
                return;
            }

            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // tell the camera to update its matrices.
            mCamera.update();

            // tell the SpriteBatch to render in the
            // coordinate system specified by the camera.
            mBatch.setProjectionMatrix(mCamera.combined);

            mBatch.begin();
            mProgressLine.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Rectangle);
            mProgressLine.rect(0 + mStage.getWidth() / 5, mStage.getHeight() / 2, mStage.getWidth() - mStage.getWidth() / 2.5f, DesignUtil.percentToPixel(5, mStage.getHeight()));
            mProgressLine.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
            mProgressLine.end();
            mProgressLine.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.FilledRectangle);
            mProgressLine.filledRect(0 + mStage.getWidth() / 5, mStage.getHeight() / 2, (mStage.getWidth() - mStage.getWidth() / 2.5f) * CustomApplication.getAssetManager().getProgress(), DesignUtil.percentToPixel(5, mStage.getHeight()));
            mProgressLine.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
            mProgressLine.end();
            mBatch.end();
        }

        @Override
        public void pause() {

        }

        @Override
        public void resume() {

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            mBatch.dispose();
            mStage.dispose();
            mProgressLine.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user2685747 I added my complete Activity class which extends from AndroidApplication. If you still have errors, tell me which one so I can help.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you CAN use the Android UI elements from Libgdx. That way, you can get the behavior you want, but not the method you want.

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements

http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Comment: Yes I knew about it, but still thanks a lot, it may help anyone else!